# Am I reading this definition of analytic function correctly?

Tags: real-analysis

Wikipedia states:

> an analytic function is an infinitely differentiable function such that the Taylor series at any point $x_{0}$ in its domain
>
> $$T(x)=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }{\frac {f^{(n)}(x_{0})}{n!}}(x-x_{0})^{n}$$
>
> converges to $f(x)$ for $x$ in a neighborhood of $x_{0}$ pointwise.

I was somewhat confused by the wording. Just to check that I got this correctly, can I rephrase this as:

> an analytic function is an infinitely differentiable function such that for any $x_0$, there is a neighborhood $N_{x_0}$ such that for all $x\in N_{x_0}$,
>
> $$f(x)=T(x):=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }{\frac {f^{(n)}(x_{0})}{n!}}(x-x_{0})^{n}$$

Is this rephrasing correct?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: Analytic : represented by a power series on some disk around every point. This power series is necessary the Taylor series.